# Excel VSTO, Workbook Open Event Not Firing

Tags: vb.net, excel, vsto

I've got the code below in an Excel Addin Proect in VB.Net:

```
Public Class ThisAddIn

    Private Sub Application_WorkbookOpen(Wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook) Handles Application.WorkbookOpen
        Beep()
        MsgBox("fad")
    End Sub
End Class
```

This was generated by the VB editor. It is the event handler for when the workbook is opened. When I press F5 and run the code, apparently the event handler doesn't execute. Any Ideas?

Edit: The event handler will run if I open a workbook from the workbook that opens, but will not run for the original workbook itself.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you know the **Open** event is not called when Excel starts, the event is called only when you **open** an existing workbook.

There is an event **NewWorkbook* which interestingly enough is not fired either ...

I found a way how to handle with this but have to say I tested only for 1 minute, give it a try and let us know

```
Public Class ThisAddIn
    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
        AddHandler Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.WorkbookOpen, AddressOf MyWorkbookOpenEvent
        AddHandler Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.NewWorkbook, AddressOf MyNewWorkbookEvent
        If Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks.Count = 1 Then MyWorkbookOpenEvent(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks(1))
    End Sub

    Private Sub MyWorkbookOpenEvent(ByVal Wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook)
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("OPEN workbook event")
    End Sub

    Private Sub MyNewWorkbookEvent(ByVal Wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook)
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("NEW Workbook event")
    End Sub

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown
        RemoveHandler Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.WorkbookOpen, AddressOf MyWorkbookOpenEvent
        RemoveHandler Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.NewWorkbook, AddressOf MyNewWorkbookEvent
    End Sub
End Class
```